# How to maintain background color of HTML <button> while changing it's border radius?

Tags: html, css, button

On applying border radius to a button, the button's background color changes from this:

```css
button{
  height:200px;
  width:500px;
   /*border-radius:10px; */
}
```

```html
<html>
  <button>My Button</button>
</html>
```

To this:

```css
button{
  height:200px;
  width:500px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <button>My Button</button>
</html>
```

How can I get the background color to remain after changing border-radius or border color .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `background` to a **[`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)**.

```css
button{
  height:200px;
  width:500px;
  border-radius:10px; 
  background:linear-gradient(white, #e0e0e0);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <button>My Button</button>
</html>
```